# Elasticsearch command to list all scripted fields used ? Also how to delete a specific scripted field?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have accidentally created some wrong scripted field in kibana-4 and now my elasticsearch is not working and throwing exceptions. I am looking for a command to list all the scripted fields currently used by the elasticsearch and delete the one that is causing trouble to me.

Comment: You can view the scripted fields in kibana.  I'm away from my system, but I think it's Settings->Indices, and then you get fields and scripted fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily/add delete a scripted field in Kibana 4.

Just go to Settings, select Indices tab, click on your index name , selected scripted fields tab beside the fields tab & add/delete accordingly :)

Comment: Thnx @yuvraj, But what you just suggested is a GUI way to listing the scripted fields. What I am looking for is a command to list them using the terminal console.